# Extraction of Type Scheme

Tags: coq, coq-extraction

I'm trying to extract some file system code that I've written in Coq. I want to replace my `FileIO` Monad with Haskell's `IO` Monad. My code looks like this:

```
Variable FileIO : Type -> Type.
Variable sync : FileIO unit.

Extract Inlined Constant sync => "synchronize".
Extract Inlined Constant FileIO => "IO".

Recursive Extraction append.
```

Replacing `sync` is no problem, but when I try to replace `FileIO` with `IO` I get the following error:

```
Error: The type scheme axiom  FileIO needs 1 type variable(s).
```

What does this error mean, and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a limitation. You need to provide an argument to `FileIO` and you're not allowed to inline it.

```
Extract Constant FileIO "x" => "IO x".
```